# Delete row from sql table where values not found in another table with multiple joins

Tags: sql, join, exists, delete-row

I have the following query which returns the desired data.  What I want to do is delete that data, however when I change the Select DQ.* to DELETE FROM DQ, I get an error indicating that

> '... not updatable because the modification affects multiple base table'

I need to delete entries from the tbaccess_groupPermission table where appropriate module records are not found in the tbaccess_companyModules table.

```
WITH DQ AS
(
SELECT GP.* FROM tbaccess_groupPermission GP
JOIN tbaccess_groups G ON GP.GroupID = G.ID
WHERE G.CompanyID=6
AND GP.RoleName NOT IN
(
select Distinct(R.RoleName)
FROM tbAccess_Roles R
INNER JOIN tbAccess_CompanyModules C on R.ModuleID = C.ModuleID
WHERE C.CompanyID = 6) 
) 
SELECT * FROM DQ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change the `WITH` statement to use an `IN` clause?

Something like

```
WITH DQ AS
(
SELECT GP.* FROM tbaccess_groupPermission GP
WHERE GP.GroupID IN (SELECT G.ID FROM tbaccess_groups G WHERE G.CompanyID=6)
AND GP.RoleName NOT IN
(
select Distinct(R.RoleName)
FROM tbAccess_Roles R
INNER JOIN tbAccess_CompanyModules C on R.ModuleID = C.ModuleID
WHERE C.CompanyID = 6) 
)
```

Comment: Ok, I had tried that before, but tried again as suggested - and it worked!  Thank you!!  'DELETE FROM tbaccess_GroupPermission WHERE ID IN'